# How to change between Hiragana and Katakana using a shortcut on mozc?

Tags: shortcut-keys, japanese, mozc

i tried a lot of stuff, then i got it to switch from hiragana to katakana using shift + space, but it wouldn't change back, then i tried another thing, now i can switch from katakana to hiragana but i can't vice-versa, i need help, since switching between it is getting quite annoying, i tried looking on the internet, but they didn't work, i also asked on r/learnjapanese put the post got removed and i can't really ask again since my Reddit account got suspended temporarily, so this is the last place i can really ask.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you all changed and maybe even broke by "trying a lot of stuff", but you *should* be able to convert what you just typed.

For example, if you type

ひらがな

and then immediately after press the F7 key, it should change to full-with katakana like

ヒラガナ

Please note that this applies to what you already typed, not what you will type after pressing F7.

There are other shortcuts as well. For example, F6 converts to hiragana, F8 converts to half-width and so fort. You can check what shortcuts are currently set on your system in the Mozc Settings

```
/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=config_dialog
```

There, press the "Customize" button for the keymap style.

Comment: yeah, i know that but i want it to switch to the other input, like i'm using hiragana, then i press the shortcut and it switches to katakana, then when i'm done writing in katakana i switch to hiragana.

Comment: @Caio As far as I know, there are no keyboard shortcuts defined for this in the default configuration. Or rather, the shortcuts that _are_ defined are bound to keys that don't exist on western keyboards, like the hiragana key or the katakana key. You can add your own shortcuts by customizing the keymap style in the Settings tool I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck, FYI, Japanese keyboard has these Kiragana/Katakana key and Convert or No-convert keys on JIS (Japan Industrial Standard) keyboard. But that was for the Japanese word-processor back in 1980s. Today, these 3 keys do nothing related to the IME... Some people find them useful for extra mod keys... JIS keyboard sucks in my mind, everytime I buy a new computer that comes with it... I have a dozen of them... never been used